# Is there a way to customise a Kafka Deserializer in Kafka Ingress of Flink stateful function?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-statefun

In my project, I am going to use flink statefun kafka ingress for consuming avro-serialized records from kafka, but it seems there is no config parameter for users to specify the deserilizer for deserializing the kafka record's key, in the source code [RoutableKafkaIngressDeserializer](https://github.com/apache/flink-statefun/blob/master/statefun-flink/statefun-flink-io-bundle/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/statefun/flink/io/kafka/binders/ingress/v1/RoutableKafkaIngressDeserializer.java), I also noticed the key is directly converted to String from bytearray.

I tried to specify the deserializer by kafka consumer property key.deserializer, but it is not a feasible solution according to [flink kafka additional properties](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.14/docs/connectors/datastream/kafka/#additional-properties)

I found kafka deserializer can be specified through datastream API [Kafka deserializer](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.14/docs/connectors/datastream/kafka/#deserializer), unfortunatelly, this configuration seems not available in flink statefun kafka ingress for now.

Comment: Have you looked at the official documentation? You can specify your input type by implementing your custom class, and defining it in your module.yaml.
Details: https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-statefun-docs-release-3.2/docs/sdk/java/#types, https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-statefun-docs-release-3.2/docs/modules/io/apache-kafka/

Comment: I am afraid it only works for value not the kafka ingress record key. And I found a way to deserialize the key using the Flink statefun extension module SDK